# Invariant Violation: ViewPropTypes has been removed from React Native. Migrate to ViewPropTypes exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'

Tags: react-native

Since the ViewPropTypes has been removed from 'react-native' and the packages using it didn't update. this error appears after building the app

```js
ERROR  Invariant Violation: ViewPropTypes has been removed from React Native. Migrate to ViewPropTypes exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'.   
ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
      This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
      This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
```

packages I'm using:

```js
"@react-native-clipboard/clipboard": "^1.10.0",
"@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.5.12",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^14.11.0",
"@react-native-firebase/auth": "^14.9.4",
"@react-native-firebase/database": "^14.11.0",
"@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^14.11.0",
"@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^7.2.2",
"@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "github:react-native-masked-view/masked-view",
"@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.4.1",
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.1",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.1",
"axios": "^0.27.2",
"base-64": "^1.0.0",
"num-words": "^1.2.2",
"numeral": "^2.0.6",
"pdf-lib": "^1.17.1",
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "^0.69.0",
"react-native-blob-util": "^0.16.1",
"react-native-country-picker-modal": "^2.0.0",
"react-native-date-picker": "^4.2.2",
"react-native-fbsdk-next": "^8.0.5",
"react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.5.0",
"react-native-html-to-pdf": "^0.12.0",
"react-native-pdf": "^6.5.0",
"react-native-picker-select": "^8.0.4",
"react-native-progress": "^5.0.0",
"react-native-radio-input": "^0.9.4",
"react-native-ratings": "^8.1.0",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.2.5",
"react-native-screens": "^3.13.1",
"react-native-share": "^7.5.0",
"react-native-signature-canvas": "^4.3.1",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^9.1.0",
"react-native-webview": "^11.21.2",
"react-scripts": "^5.0.1"
```

Any solution?

Comment: Did you try what the error message says? `Migrate to ViewPropTypes exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'.`

Comment: Because when i do that i get this
`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'ReactCurrentActQueue$1.isBatchingLegacy')`

Answer (score 112):

I can recommend doing the steps outlined in this [github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/33734#issuecomment-1190506381) discussion.

### Steps

1. Install [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package), this will later be used to make the changes more persistent.
2. Install *deprecated-react-native-prop-types* by running `npm install deprecated-react-native-prop-types` or `yarn add deprecated-react-native-prop-types`
3. Now you have to *hack* the *node_modules*. Go to *node_modules/react-native/index.js* starting around line 436 and change this:

   ```
   // Deprecated Prop Types
   get ColorPropType(): $FlowFixMe {
     invariant(
       false,
       "ColorPropType has been removed from React Native. Migrate to " +
         "ColorPropType exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'.",
    );
   },
   get EdgeInsetsPropType(): $FlowFixMe {
     invariant(
       false,
       "EdgeInsetsPropType has been removed from React Native. Migrate to " +
         "EdgeInsetsPropType exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'.",
     );
   },
   get PointPropType(): $FlowFixMe {
     invariant(
       false,
       "PointPropType has been removed from React Native. Migrate to " +
        "PointPropType exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'.",
    );
   },
   get ViewPropTypes(): $FlowFixMe {
    invariant(
      false,
      "ViewPropTypes has been removed from React Native. Migrate to " +
        "ViewPropTypes exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'.",
    );
   },
   ```

to this:

```
  // Deprecated Prop Types
  get ColorPropType(): $FlowFixMe {
    return require("deprecated-react-native-prop-types").ColorPropType
  },
  get EdgeInsetsPropType(): $FlowFixMe {
    return require("deprecated-react-native-prop-types").EdgeInsetsPropType
  },
  get PointPropType(): $FlowFixMe {
    return require("deprecated-react-native-prop-types").PointPropType
  },
  get ViewPropTypes(): $FlowFixMe {
    return require("deprecated-react-native-prop-types").ViewPropTypes
  },
```

4. Run `npx patch-package react-native` to save the patch.
5. Rebuild the app.

> Only thing to keep in mind is that this patch will need to be reapplied with every upgrade to react-native, or until the libraries in question are updated to import from deprecated-react-native-prop-types instead.

Props to [goguda](https://github.com/goguda) for providing this answer.

*EDIT:*

As suggested by [Ethan Hermsey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12248232/ethan-hermsey), add the following script to your *package.json*: `"postinstall": "patch-package"`

in order to automate the process after using `npm i`.

Comment: Hey, that's a great solution not just to solve this error but for other situations on third party libraries like that. thanks a lot!

Comment: All thanks to goguda. This solution really saved my ass because I needed a fix for several third party libraries. Happy to share it and help other people out.

Comment: Thank you very much @Gh05d. You save my day. 
I was facing this issue with `react-native-qrcode-scanner` module.

Comment: Didn't work for me, just changed the error message to: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.Image.propTypes.source')

Comment: really cool!! tks!!!

Comment: @Justin You can apply all files for node_modules in commit https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/3f629049ba9773793978cf9093c7a71af15e3e8d

Comment: I really want this to work but when I follow all of these steps, I get this message: Not creating patch file for package 'react-native'
⁉️  There don't appear to be any changes. What the heck?

Comment: This sounds like you didn't save the file you changed or something. Maybe it was in the wrong folder? Just guessing here.

Comment: maybe you could add that you can put a "postinstall" script into the package.json with the value "patch-package" to automate it :)

Answer (score 18):

In case anyone is getting the error with react-native-snap-carousel this is another way to fix it:

```
npm i --save react-native-snap-carousel@4.0.0-beta.6
```

[github issue](https://github.com/meliorence/react-native-snap-carousel/issues/928)

Comment: this saved me a lot of headache on a project following an expo update, thanks!

Answer (score 12):

I had the same error I followed the following steps and I resolved it. It arises because react-native has removed the view prop types from the library but still some external modules require the use of it.

1. Run the command in the terminal

```js
npm i deprecated-react-native-prop-types@2.2.0
```

2. Go to the node modules and find the module that you are using in my case it was "react-native-camera"
3. Navigate into the `src` folder of the module file (in my case it was in RNCamera.js) and look for

```js
import {
       findNodeHandle,
       Platform,
       NativeModules,
       ViewPropTypes,
       requireNativeComponent,
       View,
       ActivityIndicator,
       Text,
       StyleSheet,
       PermissionsAndroid,
     } from 'react-native';
```

In the following code remove the ViewPropTypes and paste the following command below this

```js
import { ViewPropTypes } from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types';
```

save the file and run it again, Hope it helps <3

Answer (score 9):

I had the same error using react-native-camera. I fix it by installing `npm i deprecated-react-native-prop-types@2.2.0` and replacing in `node_modules/react-native-camera`

all imports in files.

```js
import { ViewPropTypes } from 'react-native';
```

for

```js
import { ViewPropTypes } from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types';
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error using react-native-snap-carousel. I fix it by replacing in node_modules/react-native-snap-carousel

Check All files and change this import

```
import { ViewPropTypes } from 'react-native';
```

with this and this error gone

```
import { ViewPropTypes } from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types';
```

Comment: I think the author of this lib needs to update his code base so this deprecation error would not occur.  the above fix worked very well.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing this problem (Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable.) when I used `drawer navigation`
so I follow [this step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72755476/invariant-violation-viewproptypes-has-been-removed-from-react-native-migrate-t/73135908#73135908)

I hope this will help someone

Comment: It worked for the same error here too, but in a different package

Answer (score 0):

EDIT -
For me.. This error represented a mismatch violation with an older version of Expo Go in the simulator and the version of Expo Cli I was running. It was important that I upgraded each version of Expo one version at a time. It had nothing to do with my React or React Native code. As of Expo 46, expo upgraded the ios simulator with a prompt so the fix below i only relevant below version 46.

In my case, I am using Expo managed Workflow and this error popped up after I upgraded Expo Go on the ios simulator, which prompted me to have to upgrade Expo because the simulator wouldn't allow the version of Expo I was using (43) . After upgrading Expo, and running the simulator, I was greeted with this error, which sent me down a rabbit hole, (where this question is one of the only relevant search results) of trying to upgrade react native to be compatible with the new Expo version and so on. However, this error persisted no matter what version of react native I was using. So finally I tested a different project on the same simulator and found that the actual simulator was throwing the same error on a new project with all the latest versions.

My solution was too simple.

Install a new Simulator with the version of Expo the project is running on. While in the root of the Expo project, in the terminal, I ran

```
expo client:install:ios
```

After that, for this project these exact errors completely went away and the Simulator ran fine. I know that this is probably not a long-term fix for the actual error and that upgrading Expo and React Native is going to be necessary and this may not be the issue for many people, but in order to keep working on the project, this allowed me to move forward.

Answer (score 0):

In node_modules/react-native/index.js

I changed:

```
get ViewPropTypes(): $FlowFixMe {
    invariant(
      false,
      'ViewPropTypes has been removed from React Native. Migrate to ' +
        "ViewPropTypes exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'.",
    );
    return require('deprecated-react-native-prop-types').ViewPropTypes;
  }
```

to:

```
get ViewPropTypes(): $FlowFixMe {
    console.warn(
      'ViewPropTypes has been removed from React Native. Migrate to ' +
        "ViewPropTypes exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'.",
    );
    return require('deprecated-react-native-prop-types').ViewPropTypes;
  }
```

Fix found here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lk0PuqXa53Q

Answer (score 0):

To temporarily suppress the warning about ViewPropTypes in your app, you can add the following snippet at the start of your app (usually in App.js):

```
import { LogBox } from 'react-native';

LogBox.ignoreLogs(['ViewPropTypes']);
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue after upgrading to the new RN v0.69. Changing `node_modules/react-native-camera` would solve the problem locally. However, we know that when the node dependencies need to be installed from scratch - in a CI/CD process for example - the changes at 3rd party library need to be done over again. So, a better solution I suggest is to intercept the `react-native-camera` component at build runtime level using the [`babel-plugin-module-resolver`](https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver/blob/master/DOCS.md) as suggested here https://github.com/psycheangel/deprecated-with-module-resolver. I did another way because this solution did not work for me since it's more generic and got conflict with other stuffs I have on my project. Still using the same babel resolver plugin but to address the specific problem with `react-native-camera` component, this is the way I did based on the above solution by [psycheangel](https://github.com/psycheangel):

Step 1

Install the babel resolver plugin and the turn around dependency:

```bash
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-module-resolver deprecated-react-native-prop-types
```

or

```bash
yarn add --dev babel-plugin-module-resolver deprecated-react-native-prop-types
```

Step 2

create `resolver/react-native/index.js` with this code:

```js
import * as ReactNative from 'react-native'
import * as DeprecatedPropTypes from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'

delete ReactNative['ColorPropType']
delete ReactNative['EdgeInsetsPropType']
delete ReactNative['ImagePropTypes']
delete ReactNative['PointPropType']
delete ReactNative['TextInputPropTypes']
delete ReactNative['TextPropTypes']
delete ReactNative['ViewPropTypes']

module.exports = {
  ...ReactNative,
  ...DeprecatedPropTypes,
}
```

Step 3

add module resolver plugin config to `babel.config.js`:

```js
const path = require('path')
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    [
      'module-resolver',
      {
        root: ['.'],
        resolvePath(sourcePath, currentFile) {
          if (
            sourcePath === 'react-native' &&
            currentFile.includes('react-native-camera/src/RNCamera.js')
          ) {
            console.log('resolver', sourcePath, currentFile)
            return path.resolve(__dirname, 'resolver/react-native')
          }
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
}
```

Comment: Not working for me.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me, just installed these packages. Try it, it might help you as well.

```
expo install react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view
```