# React Native: Error upgrading to expo SDK 46

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, expo

I am getting a lot of errors when I updated my React Native app project to expo SDK 46.

```
ERROR  Invariant Violation: ViewPropTypes has been removed from React Native. Migrate to ViewPropTypes exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'.
ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
```

I searched for any reference of "Viewproptypes" in my project but i haven't found any.

I tried this solution [Invariant Violation: ViewPropTypes has been removed from React Native. Migrate to ViewPropTypes exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72755476/invariant-violation-viewproptypes-has-been-removed-from-react-native-migrate-t/73135908#73135908) but i keep having the same error.

My dependencies are:

```
"expo": "^46.0.0",
"react": "18.0.0",
"react-native": "0.69.6"
```

Any solution?