# How to fix react-native ViewPropType error in eas built apk in production?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, eas

I've been building my expo app but when i try to run it it give a ViewPropTypes error.

I've fixed the error in debug mode by changing the react-native package code by updating it to use
deprecated-view-prop-types and the app runs but when i build it into an apk using eas
the error occurs again.

I think eas installs the broken react-native package which causes the error again.
I've tried adding the fixed react-native code into the git repo hoping that it makes eas use the
fixed react-native package but it failed so i want to know how to make eas compile with the fixed
react-native package.

Here is the link on how to fix the react-native ViewPropTypes error [Invariant Violation: ViewPropTypes has been removed from React Native. Migrate to ViewPropTypes exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72755476/invariant-violation-viewproptypes-has-been-removed-from-react-native-migrate-t)

> ```
> Here is the log on android when the app crashes01-31 18:26:47.548 18926 18982 E ReactNativeJS: Invariant Violation: ViewPropTypes has been removed from React Native. Migrate to ViewPropTypes exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'.01-31 18:26:47.577 18926 18982 E ReactNativeJS: Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 11): Systrace, JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler, RCTLog, RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter, GlobalPerformanceLogger, JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient, RCTEventEmitter.01-31 18:26:47.577 18926 18982 E ReactNativeJS:         A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
> ```